# Why does vim insert an underlined e that can only be escaped with <esc>?

Tags: mode

It seems like I have found a really strange mode by accident in vim, if you hit `<C-;>` in vim, it replaces whatever character at the cursor with an underlined e, and if I type it, it replaces letters with an underlined version of that character, and the background for the cursor is blue.

According to ChatGPT, `<C-;>` doesn't have any functionality, but my vim (version 9.0 with an Ubuntu terminal). It appears to be a mode because `<Esc>` puts it back into normal mode, yet there aren't any indicators of what's going on. Also, `<C-C>` (my favorite way to switch back to normal mode) doesn't do anything, the underlines and blue background characters remain.

Also, getting rid of it through remapping does NOT work. The behavior described above continues despite it:
`nnoremap <C-;> iBlurp<Esc>`

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. Could you tell us the version of Vim that you are using `:version` it looks to me that this more a bug than a feature and that it should be reported in the Vim GitHub [tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues)

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by starting Vim in bare mode: `vim -i NONE -u NONE`?

Comment: What happens when you press `<C-;>` in your terminal without Vim running?

Comment: @Vivian yes i will when i have access to my desktop. And as far as ChatGPT, obviously acurrate information is never gauranteed, but that doesn't really matter if you are just testing code and shortcuts...@Friedrich ill try that too.

Comment: ChapGPT has lost a lot of credit in this forum. My 2 cents advice: better not to refer to it here if you want to be taken seriously ;-)

Comment: oh, i don't need to be taken seriously, for me programming is currently just a hobby ;-). Anyways, ```<C+;>``` is not supposed to do anything on vim and the linux terminal, but on both [for me] it produces the behavior i described in my question, which is wierd and i also really should map that combination to something in vim because it doesn't appear to serve any practical purpose.

Comment: Also, ```<C-.>``` produces this same behavior, but not in the terminal.

Comment: ChatGPT is correct that `<C-;>` doesn't have any functionality, at least not in standard terminals. I think with "Ubuntu terminal" you mean gnome-terminal (or has the default changed to something else? I haven't used it in a while). I can't reproduce it there. Maybe there is a shortcut in your terminal? What does pressing `<C-v><C-;>` in insert mode produce? That should insert the literal character(s) vim sees.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that is by default has no functionality, which means it's theoretically a good key for mapping. When i press ```<C-v>``` before, it does exactly the same thing, so that is probably why my attempt to map it as something else failed. I tried googling this problem, and ChatGPT says that it's "probably a custom keybinding", which should be wrong because i haven't mapped anything to the ```;``` key. I just checked and i haven't made any keyboard mappings for Ubuntu, even though i have made several for vim.